# Braintree creditcard in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, braintree

I'm currently using a drop in UI to complete a payment transaction flow. I'm able to successfully save a payment nonce to the braintree server associated with my customer id with their Drop-In UI.

What I'd like to do, is instead of showing the Drop in UI shown below, instead return the default payment of my customer and show it as a `UITableViewCell`. The `UITableViewCell` would look the one in Braintree's Drop-in UI.

Is this possible?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. There are a couple things you'll need to do:

#### Fetch customer payment methods

To get the saved payment methods for your customer, you can use [`-[BTClient fetchPaymentMethodsWithSuccess:failure:]`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/55c6a8c2c1dd1634aad78b272308a3893d0ac0c5/Braintree/API/@Public/BTClient.h#L58-L63).

The first method in the list is your customer's default payment method.

#### Display the payment method(s)

You can [`BTUIPaymentMethodView`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/d31b20ac179bddca5b28d2235ce00c391ca9a560/Braintree/UI/Views/Payments%20Components/BTUIPaymentMethodView.h), if you like. This isn't a `UITableViewCell` per se, but it's close to what you want, and has a simple API. This is the code used to display the selected payment method in the main Braintree drop-in UI.

Or if you actually do require a UITableViewCell exactly like in your screenshot in the question, take a look at the `Braintree/Drop-In` [implementation of `-[BTDropInSelectPaymentMethodViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/d31b20ac179bddca5b28d2235ce00c391ca9a560/Braintree/Drop-In/BTDropInSelectPaymentMethodViewController.m#L47-L96). The logic in here is pretty straightforward. This is the code used in the Braintree drop-in payment method selection UI.

Perhaps it would be worth us moving this code to `Braintree/UI` so it's more standalone and reusable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the through answer ! v.zero is great but the new documentation does't go beyond very cursory applications of the drop in ui. This is excellent !

Comment: I'm actually implementing a change to pull this code out and make it more reuseable. One question. Is the default payment always at location 0 when returning `[BTClient fetchPaymentMethodsWithSuccess:failure:]` ? Thanks ! I'll submit a pull request soon

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to determine the default payment method on the client side. `fetchPaymentMethods` sorts the payment methods by when they were last used and added.